# Missing packages while trying to install DaVinci Resolve 16 and can't find all those packages

Tags: apt, package-management

I literally pasted all the missing packages. They were in `name.so.version` format with the path of resolve and a hex that was probably a memory location, from `ldd` output. I tried to install them all at once and majority of them wasn't found in the official repository. Any idea where can I find them?

```
linux-vdso
libc++
libc++abi
libcudart
libcublas
libnvrtc
libQt5Concurrent
libQt5Core
libQt5Gui
libQt5Multimedia
libQt5Network
libQt5OpenGL
libQt5Sql
libQt5Svg
libQt5Widgets
libQt5Xml
libQt5XmlPatterns
libGLU
libGL
fusionscript
libluajit-5.1
libtbbmalloc
libtbbmalloc_proxy
libgpudetect
libXxf86vm
libfreetype
libXext
libSM
libICE
libX11
libbz2
libxml2
libm
libdl
librt
libavformat
libavcodec
libavutil
libMXF
libfraunhoferdcp
libSMDK-Linux-x64
libmp4decMT
libmp4encMT
libsonyxavcenc
liblog4cxx
libaprutil-1
libapr-1
libopencv_calib3d
libopencv_core
libopencv_dnn
libopencv_features2d
libopencv_flann
libopencv_highgui
libopencv_imgcodecs
libopencv_imgproc
libopencv_ml
libopencv_objdetect
libopencv_video
libopencv_videoio
libcudnn
libSonyRawDev
libOpenCL
libgvc
libcgraph
libcdt
libxdot
libpathplan
libDNxHR
libDNxUncompressedSDK
libimf
libirc
libsvml
libArriRawSDK
libcodexhdedecoder
libgvcodec
libCrmSdk
libid3-3.8
libpthread
libssl
libcrypto
librsvg-2
libBMDDavUI
libCg
libCgGL
libgcc_s
libc
ld-linux-x86-64
libstdc++
libGLX
libGLdispatch
libpng16
libz
libuuid
libbsd
libxcb
libicuuc
liblzma
libltdl
libasound
libexpat
libcrypt
libintlc
libcudart
libgdk_pixbuf-2.0
libgio-2.0
libpangocairo-1.0
libcairo
libpangoft2-1.0
libpango-1.0
libgobject-2.0
libfontconfig
libcroco-0.6
libglib-2.0
libXau
libXdmcp
libicudata
libgmodule-2.0
libmount
libselinux
libresolv
libpixman-1
libxcb-shm
libxcb-render
libXrender
libharfbuzz
libthai
libfribidi
libffi
libpcre
libblkid
libpcre2-8
libgraphite2
libdatrie
```

Comment: I pasted the name of the packages i need.
From `ldd` output. `ldd /opt/resolve/bin/resolve`.  `libdatrie.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdatrie.so.1 (0x00007fe38f4db000)`, example output.
Into askubuntu.

Comment: No easy way around it: You will need to Google each lib to determine the correct package name. Some packages may pull in more than one lib on the list, so watch the output.

Comment: Yea, i guess so :(